# Database failover scenario in solr

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

Consider there are two MySQL database like **DB1** and **DB2** which contains the same set of data. In solr application, we are pointing to the DB1 to fetch the records. If the DB1 is down due to some reason then Solr need to fetch the records from DB2 which contains the mirror data of DB1.

Is there any way to achieve this **database failover** scenario in **Solr** ?